# cannot find symbol when running unit test on Android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I'm not very familiar with Andorid and Gradle. I'm trying to run [this unit test](https://github.com/MichaelEvans/Aftermath/blob/master/aftermath-processor/src/test/java/org/michaelevans/aftermath/AftermathProcessorTest.java) from the same project after removing the `@Ignore` annotation. But I'm getting the following error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Compilation produced the following errors:

/SOURCE_OUTPUT/com/example/MainActivity$$Aftermath.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
import org.michaelevans.aftermath.IAftermathDelegate;
                                 ^
  symbol:   class IAftermathDelegate
  location: package org.michaelevans.aftermath
/SOURCE_OUTPUT/com/example/MainActivity$$Aftermath.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
public class MainActivity$$Aftermath<T extends com.example.MainActivity> implements IAftermathDelegate<T> {
                                                                                    ^
  symbol: class IAftermathDelegate
```

can someone please point out to me how to solve the problem?